# presentModalViewController calling any method in the target viewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When i call presentModalViewController

```
[self presentModalViewController:iPSPvc animated:NO];
```

is there a method i can implement in the target viewController (iPSPvc) that gets called every time this happens?

I need to make sure some updating of the view is done.

viewDidLoad gets called when i create an instance of iPSPvc so I need a method where I can do sometime similar.

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `viewWillAppear` method

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
 //your code goes here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

what's with `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

If I've understood your question aright, the above method (or one its close cousins) in your target viewController. This gets called every time the controller's view is about to appear, not just when the view is first loaded.